# Mac OS X Themes Manager

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, themes

does anyone know what a good client for changing/managing themes in Mac OS X 10.6.x Snow Leopard? I was looking at a few, but it seems that ShapeShifter doesn't work with Leopard's new themeing updates, and I had heard that Magnifique had problems (e.g, with iTunes). Does anyone know of other (or whether magnifique is fine) theme managers?

Thank you  -- Kyle

Comment: Magnifique [doesn't seem to be fine](http://magnifique.pcwizcomputer.com/forum/portal.php).

Comment: [Macthemes' news section](http://macthemes.net/) mentions Magnifique as the only Leopard solution. Given that it doesn't seem to work for SL...